# Why does a 16bit LFSR pass all Diehard tests?

Tags: random, bluespec

I made a implementation of an LFSR in Hardware. It was based on the LFSR from the wikipedia page. It has the same output.

It pass all the tests for dieharder, however, if I plot the pairs I get this not very random lines in 2D

[2D plot of the LFSR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCoOG.png)

So, how can I have a strong statistical test that could prove this PRNG is not ideal?

SOLVED:

I have to use comand

```
dieharder -a -f exemple_LSRF_BS_1_DH.txt -g 202
```

And add a header to the output file I have my numbers.

Comment: The spectral test should catch that behavior.  Dieharder lists it as a possible future addition.

Comment: The image I ploted is the spectral test (I think).

Comment: It looks like a pure pairwise plot to me.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_test) mentions that some popular PRNG fails for the spectral-test with dims >= 3. Your plot is only 2d.

Comment: Yes, this is a 2D pairs (x = xi, y = x(i+1)).

Comment: Try [TestU01](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/testu01/tu01.html), maybe?  I want to say that because the period is so short you shouldn't expect to pass many tests even with a perfect generator, but being just a bit generator with period co-prime to the word size means each loop is shifted by one bit from the previous.  Maybe try `dieharder -m0.1` to see if it _starts_ weak but the shifted repetitions are masking that.

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  Are you emitting the whole shift register after every update?  So each output is either the previous output divided by two, or the previous output divided by two plus 32768?  That's kind of an alarming oversight.  I'm impressed that any RNG test could miss it.  But your plot must be working with 16-bit chunks while the RNG tests probably consider 32-bit chunks or more, which should make your plot a bit fuzzier (but a clear failure).

Comment: It is exactly the same output from the wikipedia page for LFSR - even the seed. I want to implement many diferent PRNG in Hardware (Bluespec and FPGA) and show how each one performs.

The final goal is a Mersenne Twister working on multiple FPGA cores. But I need first prove that it is better than others.

Comment: You probably don't want to settle on MT.  It's an awful lot of resources for what it achieves, and if you test it thoroughly you'll find it's not really the best or the fastest.  All the high-quality, non-cryptographic PRNGs that I know of are designed for software implementation, but you'd likely get a sensible hardware implementation from [xorshift128+](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/xorshift128plus.c), or if you _absolutely_ need an insane period then [xorshift1024*](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/xorshift1024star.c).

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion. The more PRNG the better to explore the performance-resource space.
We firstly decided for MT because it would be the same as Matlab, and the lab uses some models in Matlab.

Comment: Ah, well in the lab reproducibility is often king.  If you're looking to accelerate what you do in Matlab using an FPGA then it's best you do stay with the same PRNG as that.  Although, if you could configure Matlab to use a more hardware-friendly PRNG, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of your plot, I'd guess that your random bitstream emits the entire register after each cycle, rather than emitting just one bit per cycle.  This means that when viewed as 16-bit words, `x_(n+1)` is either `X_n / 2` or `X_n / 2 + 32768`.  This manifests as two diagonal lines with a gradient of 0.5 (or 2.0, depending on the order and/or shift direction).

Normal usage of an LFSR would emit either one bit per cycle, or all `n` bits every `n` cycles.  This does produce some negative properties, but they're not so obvious as what you've shown.

As for why your test fails dieharder; I think there must be a flaw in your test set-up.  I modified code from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register#Fibonacci_LFSRs) to emit the 16-bit state on every cycle on stdout, and piped that into `dieharder -a -g200`, and it failed immediately on the first five tests.  That's what one would expect; even `hexdump -C` shows obvious visible patterns.

Modifying the code to emit the 16-bit state every 16 cycles, `hexdump -C` looks much more random, but dieharder still fails just the same.

Perhaps you didn't specify the generator source to dieharder, and so it used its default internal generator.  You can confirm this on line five of the output:

```
   rng_name    |rands/second|   Seed   |
        mt19937|  1.42e+08  |1473327481|
```

Even so, if you want more thorough tests for your generators, have a look at [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html).

Comment: This is the header I was using

#=================================================
# generator LFSR  seed = 1
#======================
type: d
count: 65535
numbit: 16
---------------------------
Also the comand I used was 
dieharder -f exemple.txt -a

Comment: It seems your are right.
This is the line I get.
   rng_name    |           filename             |rands/second|
        mt19937|                     exemple.txt|  1.65e+08  |